# How does 3 tick fishing work?

Tags: oldschool-runescape

I understand that a lot of things in Oldschool Runescape can be tick manipulated. One of which I am interested in is 3 tick fishing.  From my understanding, you need to perform certain actions within 3 game ticks to allow for this to work.  A common strategy I've watched streamers do is take a low level herb such as a tarromin, and some swamp tar and attempt to mix them together to make tarromin tar.  However, before you actually make the tar, you click the fishing spot.  You are suppose to perform all of these actions in 3 game ticks, with each click being on a separate tick.  So, you click the tarromin, you click the swamp tar, and then you click the fishing spot, all on separate game ticks.

What happens if you can click faster than that? Say I perform all 3 clicks within 1 game tick (0.6 seconds).  I admit, I don't think I'm quite skilled enough to do this, but I *can* do it within 2 game ticks.  Do you still benefit from tick manipulation if you can perform these actions in less than 3 game ticks? Or does it have to be 3 game ticks?

Comment: Out of curiosity, how long is a game tick in real time?

Comment: It is a little more than 0.6 seconds per tick.  Very close to 100 ticks per minute.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there will be no benefits in this specific scenario.

The general idea is that actions require a set period of time.  Fishing is normally 5t worth of time.  However, mixing herbs is only 3t worth of time.

What is happening is you do a 3t action, but right at the tick when the results are produced, you change your action from "herb mixing" to "fishing", allowing you to fish at the pace of 3t instead of 5t.

If you were to do this faster, the engine detects you changed your action, and restarts the new action instead of giving you the result.  You will actually never fish anything if you were to click faster, because the "production tick" will never take place.